# PostgreSQL set_config and set behave differently

Tags: postgresql

```
select current_setting('my.session_id');
 current_setting 
-----------------
 14
(1 row)

select set_config ( 'my.session_id', 15::text , true) ; 
 set_config 
------------
 15
(1 row)

select current_setting('my.session_id');
 current_setting 
-----------------
 14
(1 row)

set my.session_id = 15;
SET
select current_setting('my.session_id');
 current_setting 
-----------------
 15
(1 row)
```

As seen above, SET is working, but set_config is behaving slightly differently. Probably I am missing something.

Comment: Do you understand what the third argument of set_config does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set my.session_id = 14;

select current_setting('my.session_id');
 current_setting 
-----------------
 14
(1 row)

select set_config ( 'my.session_id', 15::text , false) ;
 set_config 
------------
 15
(1 row)

select current_setting('my.session_id');
 current_setting 
-----------------
 15
(1 row)
```

as per manual:

> Sets the parameter setting_name to new_value, and returns that value. If is_local is true, the new value will only apply during the
> **current transaction**. If you want the new value to apply for the rest of the **current session**, use false instead.